# Numpy Value error x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

Tags: python, numpy

Have this value error problem

- The x is an array of 0-9 10 total digits
- X is passed into the for loop and put into the equation
- Struggling with how y and x aren't the same size when the equation has run 10 times

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a = np.array([2])
b = np.array([-3])
print(f'Scalar check for 0 dimensions a {a.ndim}, b {b.ndim} x {x.ndim}')

for i in x:
    print(i)
    y = i*a + b

plt.plot(x, y)
```

***raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)***

Though it would have ran when I changed the dimensions of a and b to 1d arrays before they were scalar but that was obviously not the error causing it

Comment: In `y = i*a + b`, i is a scalar, and a and b are both arrays of shape (1,).  So y also becomes an array of size(1,).  Are you intending to add an element to y on each iteration of the loop? The current code doesn't do that - it overwrites y with a shape (1,) array each time.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwritting the y value each time. So in the end you have `y = [15]`.

You can re-write it as follows:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a = np.array(2)  <-- note the removed brackets: []
b = np.array(-3) <-- 

y = []
for i in x:
  y.append(i * a + b)
```

and even simpler approach is

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a = np.array(2)
b = np.array(-3)
y = x * a + b
```